# Django-Filter Form Displaying All Filters?

Tags: django-filter, django-filters

I've just started working with Django Filter. When I test, the filter.form shows filters for all fields and I can't get it to show only the desired filters.

Here's the filter:

```
class EmployeeFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    hire_date = django_filters.DateFilter(name='hireDate', lookup_expr='hireDate__year')
    hire_date__gte = django_filters.DateFilter(name='hireDate', lookup_expr='hireDate__gte')
    hire_date__lte = django_filters.DateFilter(name='hireDate', lookup_expr='hireDate__lte')   

    class Meta:
        model = models.Employee
        fields=['hireDate']
```

Here's the view:

```
def test_filters(request, template_name='filter-test.html'):
    from . import filters

    f = filters.EmployeeFilter(request.GET, queryset=models.Employee.objects.all()) 

    return render_to_response(template_name, locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Has anyone ever run into this? How'd you fix?

Comment: did you get this fixed? I'm seeing the same problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django-filter shows all fields instead of just the ones specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70336821/django-filter-shows-all-fields-instead-of-just-the-ones-specified)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but I was able to solve

```
class EmployeeFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
   class Meta:
     model = Employee
     fields=['hireDate']
```

In Views.py

```
def filters(request):
    employee = Employee.objects.all()
    myFilter = EmpoyeeFilter(request.GET, queryset=employee)
    employee = myFilter.qs
    context = {
        'myFilter': myFilter,
        'employee': employee,
    }
    return render(request, 'templates/index.html', context)
```

index.html file

```
<html>
<form method="get">
   {{myFilter.form}}
</form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The filter set's form plays both of Django Form's two roles:

- It enables you to display the form in your template
- It validates the incoming values.

The second of these is (arguably) the more important — certainly for Django Filter: if you remove fields from the form they **will not** be filtered against.

Your best bet is probably to just define less fields on the filter set. (If you need all fields in some cases just define two filter sets, one for each need.)

(The other option would be to define a separate Django Form with just the fields you need and use that in your template, leaving the filter set's form to do the actual validation.)

I hope that helps.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying. I am asking why all filters/fields are displaying when I have clearly defined only 1.

Comment: I see three declared fields... it's those that appear right?

Comment: No, it's every field, not just the declared. There are 20 fields showing up rather than the ones I've explicitly declared.

Comment: There is a deprecated behavior where the filterset will generate filters for all fields when `fields` isn't set or `fields = None`. It should not generate extra filters when fields is set to anything else. Are you sure there isn't a typo or that fields isn't set properly?

Answer (score 0):

models.py

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    hire_date = models.DateField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

filters.py

```
class EmployeeFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    hire_date = django_filters.DateFilter(field_name='hire_date', lookup_expr='gt')
    hire_date__gte = django_filters.DateFilter(field_name='hire_date', lookup_expr='gt')
    hire_date__lte = django_filters.DateFilter(field_name='hire_date', lookup_expr='gt')
    name__icontains = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name='name', lookup_expr='icontains')

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = {}
```

views.py

```
def employee_view(request):
    f = EmployeeFilter(request.GET, queryset=Employee.objects.all())
    return render(request, 'product/employee.html', {'filter': f})
```

templates/my-app/employee.html

```
<h1>Employee</h1>
<form method="get">
    {{ filter.form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
<ul>
    {% for employee in filter.qs %}
        {{ employee.hire_date }}<br/>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The `field_name` specifies the **name of the field in the model** ie Employee and `lookup_expr` is a string which specifies the **filter to use on the column of table** for eg `gt`, `gte`, `lt`, `lte`, `exact`, `iexact`, `contains`, `icontains`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter against a field, but do not want it in the form, you can do the following:

```
import django_filters
from django import forms


class MyFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    field = django_filters.CharFilter(
        widget=forms.HiddenInput()
    )

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['other_field', 'field']
```

The only downside is, it will show as an empty parameter in the URL, when you submit the form. But it won't affect your results, since its an empty value.