# django-filter shows all fields instead of just the ones specified

Tags: django, django-filter

In my `filters.py`:

```
class DataFilter(FilterSet):
    start_date = DateFilter(field_name='date',lookup_expr=('lt')) 
    end_date = DateFilter(field_name='date',lookup_expr=('gt'))
    date_range = DateRangeFilter(name='date')


    class Meta:
        model = DataModel
        fields = ['date', ]
```

I have also tried setting `fields = []`, but **filters of all fields** are still there.

Why is it showing all even I just only specified one (even none)? And how to fix that?

Can anyone help explain? Thank you!

In my `models.py`:

```
class DataModel(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=now)
    other_field_1 = models.CharField()
    other_field_2 = models.CharField()
    other_field_3 = models.CharField()
```

In my `views.py`:

```
class DataModelListView(LoginRequiredMixin, FilterView):
    model = DataModel
    template_name = 'datamodel_list.html'
    filter_class = DataFilter
```

I am using django 3, django-filter 21.

Comment: Shouldn't you use the specific notations [in the docs](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/usage.html), for instance name field `date__lt` rather than `start_date` ?

Comment: I also tried. But still, all fields got display.

Comment: I also tried overriding `__init__` to set `self.fields`. But it doesn't work either.

Comment: Setting `exclude` in `Meta` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

Since modifying `FilterSet.Meta` doesn't work anyway, I then tried looking at other parts of the code. Then I found changing `filter_class` to `filterset_class`  in the `FilterView` (as below) work for me!

```
class DataModelListView(LoginRequiredMixin, FilterView):
    filterset_class = DataFilter    # instead of setting filter_class
    template_name = 'datamodel_list.html'
    # model = DataModel    # Either filterset_class or model needs to be set.
```